# WordPress : Treat value in functions.php for all inner PHP files

Tags: php, wordpress

On my website, I use Polylang, but on each PHP files of my template, I have to make things with a value like Italian = 1, French = 2, default value (english) = 0

At first, I had the following condition on each PHP file :

```
if (get_locale() == 'it') {
  $lang = 1;
} elseif (get_locale() == 'fr') {
  $lang = 2;
} {
  $lang = 0;
}
```

It worked very well, but I had to add this code on each PHP file of my website, hard... I was looking for a solution with the functions.php file.

I tried :

```
function check_lang() {
  if (get_locale() == 'it') {
    $lang = 1;
  } elseif (get_locale() == 'fr') {
    $lang = 2;
  } {
    $lang = 0;
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'check_lang' );
```

But on some files, it doesn't work, the value of $lang is "it" instead of "1"...

Do I made a mistake on my code ?

Comment: your function does not return anything

Comment: `$lang` is just internal variable inside `check_lang()` function, is undefined outside this function. PHP basics.

Comment: Should I change the name of the variable ($lang_custom for example) and add a return at the end of my function ?

Comment: I've never used WordPress, but I would expect to see `return $lang;` at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to use the `$lang` variable? In your `check_lang()` function you're setting it to an integer but you're not doing anything with it. At the very least, you need a `return $lang` statement in the function but you also need additional code elsewhere to make use of the returned value.

Comment: I tried my function with return $lang, but it doesn't work. What I try to do is to have a specific value, depending on the lang used by the user. For example, if the user use the italian language, my value will be 1, by default, the value is 0. Thanks to this value, in my PHP files, I can get the correct value in my arrays (translations in arrays). I know it's the the perfect way to manage the translations...